# How to initialise Array<T> with Kotlin Native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I've been experimenting with Kotlin Multiplatform.

While it was easy to use the built Kotlin lib with iOS, Android, and JS, I'm having trouble with using the library with C.

I have the following Kotlin code

```
data class Person(val age: Int)

fun sumAges(people: Array<Person>): Int {
  var sum = 0
  for (person in people) {
      sum += person.age
  }
  return sum
}
```

Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/Qao7741qp

I'm trying to invoke the `sumAges` from C code. I've successfully initialized one `Person`.

But I wasn't able to initialize an `Array` and call `sumAges` with it.
Here is my C code so far:

```c
  libnative_ExportedSymbols* lib = libnative_symbols();
  libnative_kref_test_Person person = lib->kotlin.root.test.Person.Person(20);

  // Problematic piece
  libnative_kref_test_Person people[] = {person};
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Array peopleArray = { .pinned = people };
  libnative_KInt sum = lib->kotlin.root.test.sumAges(peopleArray);
  // Problematic piece end

  lib->DisposeStablePointer(person.pinned);

  printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
```

With this code I get segmentation fault error.

How to init an `Array` in C and pass it to Kotlin function? Is it even possible?

Comment: If you still haven't found the answer, I suggest you ask it in `#kotlin-native` channel in [kotlin slack](https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up), or in [jetbrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue)